gitleaks workflow on GitHub reports error for an autogenerated file
I have a small package posted on CRAN that uses C++.  I'm currently preparing a very minor update.
When pushing the pull request to GitHub, the gitleaks workflow (over which I have no control) fails with the error
Run gitleaks -v detect --no-git  --source .

    ○
    │╲
    │ ○
    ○ ░
    ░    gitleaks

Finding:     # Generator token: <redacted>
Secret:      <redacted>
RuleID:      generic-api-key
Entropy:     3.694386
File:        R/RcppExports.R
Line:        2
Fingerprint: R/RcppExports.R:generic-api-key:2

Finding:     // Generator token: <redacted>
Secret:      <redacted>
RuleID:      generic-api-key
Entropy:     3.694386
File:        src/RcppExports.cpp
Line:        2
Fingerprint: src/RcppExports.cpp:generic-api-key:2

1:00PM INF scan completed in 23.3ms
1:00PM WRN leaks found: 2
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

RcppExports.R is an autogenerated file, the first two lines of which are:
# Generated by using Rcpp::compileAttributes() -> do not edit by hand
# Generator token: <redacted>

Again, RccpExports.cpp is an autogenerated file, the first two lines of which are:
// Generated by using Rcpp::compileAttributes() -> do not edit by hand
// Generator token: <redacted>

I assume this is a false positive (though I have redacted the potentially sensitive information in case I am wrong).
The gitleaks repo makes two suggestions for handling this:

Use a #gitleaks:allow comment to override the default
Use a .gitleaksignore file to define an exception

It seems I can't use 1. because the RccpExports.cpp and RccpExports.R files are autogenerated.
The gitleaks repo notes that 2. is "is experimental and is subject to change in the future".  I've created a .gitleaksignore file in the root folder of my repo and have tried various formats to define the exception, but without success.
Does anyone know how I can get the workflow to pass and thus the PR to succeed?

The README file on the gitleaks repo reads in part:

You can ignore specific findings by creating a .gitleaksignore file at the root of your repo. In release v8.10.0 Gitleaks added a Fingerprint value to the Gitleaks report. Each leak, or finding, has a Fingerprint that uniquely identifies a secret. Add this fingerprint to the .gitleaksignore file to ignore that specific secret. See Gitleaks' .gitleaksignore for an example. Note: this feature is experimental and is subject to change in the future.

So, in this case, if the contents of .gitleaksignore are
R/RcppExports.R:generic-api-key:2
src/RcppExports.cpp:generic-api-key:2

the workflow succeeds.
